# Python: Print x lines after a pattern including the line with pattern

Tags: python, printing, glob

If a line starts with a number(`xyz`) in a file, I need to print(or write to a file) this line and the next `xyz+1` lines.
What's the best way to do this?

So far, I've been able to print the line that starts with an `int`. How do I print the next lines?

```
import glob, os, sys
import subprocess

file = 'filename.txt'
with open(file,'r') as f:
    data = f.readlines()
for line in data:
    if line[0].isdigit():
       print int(line)
```

If I made an iterator out of `data`, the print function skips a line every time.

```
with open(file,'r') as f:
   data = f.readlines()
x = iter(data)
for line in x:
    if line[0].isdigit():
       print int(line)
       for i in range(int(line)):
          print x.next()
```

How could I make it stop skipping lines?

Comment: What have you tried so far? We are here to help when you are stuck, not to just write the whole code for you...

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Voting to close as : Too Broad.

Comment: @lkriener have a look

Comment: Can you assume that nothing except for the number `xyz` is written in a line? Otherwise the `int(line)` you use multiple times will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Use a flag, when you find the line set it to true, then use it to write all future lines:

```
can_write = False
with open('source.txt') as f, open('destination.txt', 'w') as fw:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith(xyz):
            can_write = True
        if can_write:
            fw.write(line)
```